# How to have service know when app is killed to clear notifications?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working on an app that uses a BLE service that starts when a the user wants to connect to a device, and stops when there are no more connections. During the life of the BLE service I want to have a persistent notification that reminds the user that the app is running and using BLE. This works fine when the service is stopped while the app is still running. But the issue comes when the app is swiped away, I cannot seem to find a place where I can clear the notifiation.

Things I have tried:

1. Clearing notifications onUnbind()

```java
override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
    mNM = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    mNM!!.cancelAll()
    return super.onUnbind(intent)
}
```

2. Clearing notifications onDestroy()

```java
override fun onDestroy() {
    mNM = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    mNM!!.cancelAll()
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

3. Setting stopWithTask to false and clearing notifications in

```xml
<service
    android:name=".location.LocationService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

```java
override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    mNM = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    mNM!!.cancelAll()
    stopSelf()
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
}
```

But none of these work

I start the service by binding to it:

```java
bindService(intent, mConnectionLocation, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

Also I allow screen rotation so the MainActivity onDestroy cannot be used to unbind.

How else can I detect the app being swiped away in order to clear the persistent notification?